# Setting "scrollTop" for overflowing element via HTML/CSS (without javascript)

Tags: html, scroll, overflow, scrolltop

Suppose I have the following html:

```
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;overflow:scroll">
  ...
</div>
```

If the stuff in this div ends up overflowing, the most popular way to change the scrolling position of this item is to use jQuery.scrollTop(). However, I have a situation where I would like to set the initial scroll position of the div using the source HTML. Is there a way of doing this? All examples I see online for doing this end up using javascript.

One way I tried is to write a scrollTop property on the element, like so:

```
<div scrollTop=20 style="width:200px;height:200px;overflow:scroll">
  ...
</div>
```

However, this does not work. Surely, there must be a way to set the initial scrolling position of an overflowing item via HTML/CSS...

Here is a full version of this code that illustrates that it doesn't work- The vertical scrollbar remains at "0": http://jsfiddle.net/gueBZ/1/

Can anyone help me to make it work? Thanks so much for any pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;overflow:scroll">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div id="hello">autoscroll here</div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

then open the page as

```
page.html#hello
```

this is the only thing you can do, with HTML only

Comment: Interesting- I agree that's a partial answer to my question (and a full answer if it is the best possible.) I will see if anyone else has a better answer (i.e. one that just lets you set the scrolltop position in pixels in a more standard way) but otherwise will mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: with HTML5 you can also try "autofocus" but it works only with input tags... why you want not to use javascript? you can implement the scrolltop="" attribute by yourself

Comment: @drcode I'm nearly totally sure that this is the only thing you can do with the HTML only (including CSS)

Comment: It's part of a large-ish server-side library I'm putting together that so far is free of javascript. However, if stackoverflow says there is no solution (which seems likely at this point) then I will probably need to use javascript just for this one issue. Thanks for your time/help, Wes.

Comment: @drcode btw may be cool to have this in html5 https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=15876

Comment: Hrmmm... While that is an interesting idea.  It is disappointing.  I was hoping to find a css answer to this myself as I'm trying to put an overflow box on my user talk page and can't use JavaScript. I could use this method with a redirect from my default talkpage, but that would break the MediaWiki system's notifications of getting messages on my talk page.  It's too bad there isn't a way to manipulate the position of a div inside of the scrolling div so that it loads at the top and forces the scrollbar to appear to start at the bottom. :(